# Aws spot instance interruptions

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am new to aws and i am a little stressed in the behavior of my setup when an interruption will happen.
My spot instance is configured with terraform.

```
    resource "aws_spot_instance_request" "jenkins" {
      ami                             = var.ami_debian_buster
      instance_type                   = var.type_jenkins
      key_name                        = "test_spot"
      subnet_id                       = aws_subnet.subnet_public.id
      vpc_security_group_ids          = [aws_security_group.test.id]
      instance_interruption_behaviour = "stop"
    
      root_block_device {
        volume_type           = "gp2"
        volume_size           = "64"
        delete_on_termination = false
        tags = {
          "Name"                = "${var.vpc-name}-${var.user-environment}-spot-jenkins-root"
          "user.type"           = "disk"
          "user.project"        = var.user-project
          "user.environment"    = var.user-environment
        }
      }
```

I want to to check that the
`instance_interruption_behaviour = "stop"`
and
`delete_on_termination = false`
configurations are correct and keep data stored safely with ebs.

Is the stop instance from aws cli the same as an interruption from amazon, or is there another way I can simulate/trigger an interruption?

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to simulate this is to review the pricing history on...

https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2sp/v2/home?region=us-east-1#/spot

^ Note: change your region accordingly.

And then in your terraform specify the spot_price somewhere just around the current spot price, maybe just a few cents higher.  Using the pricing history from the spot dashboard should let you figure out a price that will make it able to start and run for a while, and get killed within' the next 24 hours or so.  But, besides that, I don't believe there's a way to simulate this.